# Can we access Virtual DataPort Administration Tool without graphical support ( GUI )?

Tags: linux, windows, uri, remote-server, denodo

Denodo file installation is located on linux remote server which i can't access GUI or full linux cli.
How can i access Virtual DataPort Administration Tool to connect JDBC with other databases?

Can somebody tell me how to do it in the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admin tool does not need to be installed on the same machine as the virtual dataport. You can install it on your client (e.g. windows) pc and connect to the vdp instance on the linux machine.

If you only want to connect to jdbc you can use the jdbc driver that is located under DENODO_HOME/tools/client-drivers/jdbc/ and use that for example with dbeaver.